# Colorize the additional spacing within a geombar

Tags: r, ggplot2

the followong code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

dt.source <- data.table(
                         category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                         value = c(100, 80, 85, 11)
                       )

bar.width <- 0.9
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_bar(data = dt.source, aes(x = category, y = value, width = bar.width),
                  stat = "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "darkgrey")
p
```

producess this barchart (vertical bars),

[image]

I know how to avoid the extra space that is added by ggplot for better readibility
using

```
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
```

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to give this additional space an extra color, e.g.

[image]

Can you please give me a hint where I can find a detailed description how control the panel.border. I'm a little hesitant to start rereading Hadley Wickhams book for this reason.

I just realized I missed to colorize the additional space on the right side of the chart, and I have to admit, that I'm not aware of some additional space on the top of the chart.

As always, many thanks in advance

Comment: I might be wrong, but "I'm a little hesitant to start rereading Hadley Wickhams book for this reason" sounds very much like you are hesitating to read the manuals and help texts, but are expecting other people to spend their time doing this.

Comment: @Henrik, I'm not hesitant to read books and I'm also not hesitant to read the manuals, this was the reason why I asked for a hint, where I'm able to find a detailed description how to control the panel.border of the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just make a couple rectangles

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=price, y=carat)) + geom_line(aes(color=color))
rect <- data.frame (xmin1 = -Inf, xmax1 = Inf, 
                    ymin1 = -Inf, ymax1 = 0,
                    xmin2 = -Inf, xmax2 = 0,
                    ymin2 = -Inf, ymax2 = Inf)
p + geom_rect(data=rect, aes(xmin=xmin1, xmax=xmax1, ymin=ymin1, ymax=ymax1), 
              color="red", fill="red", inherit.aes=FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data=rect, aes(xmin=xmin2, xmax=xmax2, ymin=ymin2, ymax=ymax2), 
              color="red", fill="red", inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[image]